# Character Picture Grid

Tags: python, list, printing, range

This is my first question in stackoverflow. Happy to join the community

This is a question in one of the books:

Say you have a list of lists where each value in the inner lists is a one-charac string, like this:

```
grid = [['.', '.', '.', '.', '.', '.'],
    ['.', '0', '0', '.', '.', '.'],
    ['0', '0', '0', '0', '.', '.'],
    ['0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '.'],
    ['.', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0'],
    ['0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '.'],
    ['0', '0', '0', '0', '.', '.'],
    ['.', '0', '0', '.', '.', '.'],
    ['.', '.', '.', '.', '.', '.']]
```

result should be:

```
..00.00..
.0000000.
.0000000.
..00000..
...000...
....0....
```

I managed to get the answer with this code:

```
Num_of_grid = range(len(grid))
for y in Num_of_grid:
    for x in Num_of_grid:
        print(grid[x][y], end = "")
    print("")
```

However, even tho it solves the problem but for some reason I get the following error: 
[Click here for error image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rgCII.png)

When I write the following
print(x, y); it shows exactly the right number of range I used in the loop... which is (0,8) but still it gives me out of range.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem her is that your grid is not square. You have 9 rows of 6 items in each. Yet, in both your loops, you are iterating over the same range of indices. To fix this, use the code:

```
Num_of_grid = range(len(grid))
Num_of_item = range(len(grid[0]))
for y in Num_of_item:
    for x in Num_of_grid:
        print(grid[x][y], end = "")
    print("")
```

Better yet, use `numpy`, to make an array, transpose it, and print the result, this way:

```
import numpy as np
g = np.array(grid)
print("\n".join("".join(l) for l in g.T))
```

Answer (score 1):

This doesn't work because the grid isn't square.  `len(grid)` is 9, but `len(grid[x])` (for all `x`) is only 6!

A less error-prone way to write an iteration over a 2d list is to simply iterate over the elements of each list:

```
for row in grid:
    for cell in row:
        print(cell, end="")
    print("")
```

Running this, I see the image is flipped on its side -- luckily it's not too hard to transpose a 2d list with `map` and `zip`!

```
for row in map(list, zip(*grid)):
    for cell in row:
        print(cell, end="")
    print("")
```

Or use `join` to just turn the whole thing into one string:

```
print("\n".join("".join(row) for row in map(list, zip(*grid))))
```

Comment: that's wack that we came up with the exact same solution code lol

Answer (score 0):

Welcome to the SO community.

So I think it would be best to reevaluate how we are printing from our 2d array/grid.

`Num_of_grid` is, after the expression is evaluated, an iterable like this: `[0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8]`. You use this range for both x **and** y iteration, even though horizontally your shape/grid is only 6 wide. What happens, then, is that at your print statement, you're trying to access a `[y]` that doesn't exist. For example, like `grid[x][6]` (7th). As expected, you get an `IndexError`, which is exactly what we expected.

So what's the best way to iterate through a 2d list?

I might suggest something more succinct:

```py
grid = [...]

for row in grid:
    for cell in row:
        print(cell, end="")
    print()
```

Answer (score 0):

This is not meeting all requirements but in order to prevent the "IndexError" you could include an except statement to ignore it like this:

```
for i in range(len(grid)):
    print()
    for x in range(len(grid)):
        try:
            print(grid[x][i], end="")
        except IndexError:
            break
```

This would include some not wanted empty lines at the beginning and ending though:

```
..OO.OO..
.OOOOOOO.
.OOOOOOO.
..OOOOO..
...OOO...
....O....
```